# `\titleformat{\chapter}` does not seem to trigger when adding a PDF as a new chapter

Tags: chapters, pdfpages

I have a workflow that involves adding some of the chapters in a report in via the `\includepdf` command from the package `pdfpages`. In this process I want some of the PDFs to be the start of a new chapter. And every chapter gets a new page before it with a title which I configure with `\titleformat{\chapter}[display]`.  I use the `addtotoc` switch to tell latex to add the PDF as a new chapter and add it to the TOC. In the past this has worked just dandy, but on my latest document I find that I'm not getting a new page with chapter title before the PDF chapter. The TOC gets updated, but there's no chapter title page. I have whittled my tex file down to the pretty minimal reproducible doc below. The file `example.pdf` is a very simple PDF document for testing. You can [download it here](https://github.com/CerebralMastication/scratchPad/raw/master/example.pdf).

What I find most mystifying is that I have another workflow that uses this same logic... and it works. And I can't figure out the material difference between the example below and the one that works properly.

Any idea?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{pdfpages}        % for inserting pdfs
\usepackage{fancyhdr}        % for fancy editing of footers
\usepackage{titlesec}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\pdfminorversion=6     %kills PDF version warning in output
\pagestyle{fancy}

%% this sets up the title page for each chapter
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\Large\filcenter\sffamily}
{\titlerule[1pt] \vspace{1pt} \titlerule \vspace{1pc}
\LARGE\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename} \thechapter}
{1pc}
{\titlerule
\vspace{1pc}%
\Huge}
[\newpage] % creates the new page

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\includepdf[ pages=-, addtotoc={1,chapter,1,A. Ex 1,p1}]{./example.pdf}
\chapter{ch 2}
\lipsum{1-5}
\includepdf[ pages=-, addtotoc={1,chapter,1,A. Ex 3,p1}]{./example.pdf}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I get the page for chapter 2; of course, since there is no `\chapter` command before the first inclusion, no separate page is added.

Comment: aaaaand I'm an idiot. I realize now that we were handcrafting section pages in the PDFs that emulated the chapter breaks. So I was totally wrong that I had had this working before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the name `addtotoc` suggests, this options simply adds an entry to the table of contents, but does not really start a chapter. If you want real chapters, including the title page, you can simply add your pdf after the begin of a chapter.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{pdfpages}        % for inserting pdfs
\usepackage{fancyhdr}        % for fancy editing of footers
\usepackage{titlesec}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\pdfminorversion=6     %kills PDF version warning in output
\pagestyle{fancy}

%% this sets up the title page for each chapter
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\Large\filcenter\sffamily}
{\titlerule[1pt] \vspace{1pt} \titlerule \vspace{1pc}
\LARGE\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename} \thechapter}
{1pc}
{\titlerule
\vspace{1pc}%
\Huge}
[\newpage] % creates the new page

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{A. Ex 1}
\includepdf[ pages=-,
% addtotoc={1,chapter,1,A. Ex 1,p1}
 ]{example-image-a4}
\chapter{ch 2}
\lipsum{1-5}
\chapter{A. Ex 3}
\includepdf[ pages=-,
% addtotoc={1,chapter,1,A. Ex 3,p1}
 ]{example-image-a4}

\end{document}
```